# libconfig++ : adding a setting to the root of the configuration tree

Tags: c++, libconfig

I have a configuration file `myCfg.cfg` that looks like this :

```
keyA = 1.0
keyB = 2
keyC = "hello"
```

Note that all the settings are at the root of the configuration tree.

I want my C++ program to load that file then add a new setting whose key is `keyD` and assign it integer value `5`. Eventually, `MyCfg` should look like this in memory :

```
keyA = 1.0
keyB = 2
keyC = "hello"
keyD = 5
```

First the `myCfg.cfg` file is loaded to construct `MyCfg`. Then the setting `keyD` must be added to the root of `MyCfg`. The [libconfig documentation](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#The-C_002b_002b-API) indicates that the `Setting::add()` method :

> add[s] a new child setting with the given name and type to the setting, which must be a group

However, there isn't any group in `MyCfg`… So how do I add a setting to the root of a Config object ?

Comment: @Gluttton I am not sure what you mean by "have you saved settings?". First I construct a `Config` instance by reading configuration from a *.cfg file, then I take that `Config` object and I try to add a setting to it. I never attempt to write a new *.cfg file that would correspond to the inputted *.cfg file plus an extra setting.

Comment: @Gluttton no I did not call `writeFile()` nor do I intend to do so. Here is more info on the context : I use a `Config` object as a collection of parameters for running my code. There are two similar routines in the code : in the first, a parameter must be chosen by the user by specifying a setting in the *.cfg file. In the other, only a single value for that parameter makes sense. Therefore, to hide it from the user I require him/her to write a configuration file without that setting and the code has to add it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all what you need is: `getRoot ()`.

Here is example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libconfig.h++"


int main ()
{
    libconfig::Config MyCfg;
    std::string file = "myCfg.cfg";

    try {
        MyCfg.readFile (file.c_str () );

        libconfig::Setting & root = MyCfg.getRoot ();
        // This also works.
        // libconfig::Setting & root = MyCfg.lookup ("");
        libconfig::Setting & keyD = root.add ("KeyD", libconfig::Setting::TypeInt);
        keyD = 5;

        // You dont need it, but it's just for testing.
        MyCfg.writeFile (file.c_str () );
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Error caused!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you ! (Damn, that was in example/example2.cpp… RTFM to myself…)

Comment: After making it work with `getRoot()` I realised that `libconfig::Setting & root = MyCfg.getRoot()` can be replaced either by ``libconfig::Setting & root = MyCfg.lookup("")` or by `libconfig::Setting & root = MyCfg.getRoot(".")`. All three work even-though `getRoot()` is by far the most elegant ! Perhaps you would like to add this remark to your answer ? I think there must have been a bug in my code and it got me confused… I edited my question in consequence. Once again, thanks for the help !

Comment: I've added remark to my answer about `lookup ("")`. But version `MyCfg.getRoot(".")` doesn't work for my (I can't compile it and it's and this corresponds to the documentation, because there are not version `getRoot` with parameters).

Comment: My mistake : it was `MyCfg.lookup(".")`, not `MyCfg.getRoot(".")`